# Download a PDF file instead of displaying it with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, download

I am generating PDF file using CodeIgniter and [R&OS pdf class](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/).
But now the problem is that the pdf is displayed to the browser.
I instead want it to be downloaded.
Here is my code :

```
$this->load->library('cezpdf');

        $data['users'] = $this->user->get_all_ayant_droits();

        foreach($data['users'] as $user) {
            $db_data[] = array('name' => $user->nom, 'department' => $user->Department, 'status' => $user->Status);
        }

        $col_names = array(
            'name' => 'Noms et Prenoms',
            'department' => 'Département',
            'status' => 'Status'
        );

        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($db_data, $col_names, 'Ayant droit Base Loisirs de Kribi', array('width'=>550));
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
```

What is missing for this controller to send the file to download ?

Comment: Take a look at the Download Helper. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: I already looked at it @Craig, but from what I read, I need a file first. And in my case, I have no file path or name...

Comment: You don't need a file, you can create one. I don't know if it would work, but try this; `force_download('download.pdf', $this->cezpdf->ezStream());` This is downloading your data as "download.pdf"

Comment: It is not working, it is behaving the same as if I just displayed it. No download.

Comment: Try this one. $this->cezpdf->ezStream(array('download' => 1));  I got this from documentation http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/api/classes/Cezpdf.html#method_ezStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the argument to the function ezStream

```
$this->cezpdf->ezStream(array $options);
```

`$options 'compress' => 0/1` to enable compression. For compression level please use `$this->options['compression'] =` at the very first point. Default: 1
`'download' => 0/1` to display inline (in browser) or as download. Default: 0

Comment: Can you write it on a line please ?

Comment: $this->cezpdf->ezStream(array('download'=>1));

Answer (score 0):

You can use Download Helper https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html?

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = $this->cezpdf->ezStream(); 
force_download("PDF_filename.pdf", $data);
```

You can also use ouput variable by setting proper header value.

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="PDF_filename.pdf"');
$this->output->set_content_type('application/pdf')
             ->set_output($this->cezpdf->ezStream());
```

here by setting content type to  **appication/pdf** so browser identify content is pdf and **Content-Disposition: attachment** force to download the file.

Hope this helps. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: The first suggestion behaves like there is no donwload and just displays the pdf on browser, the second suggestion generates an error : Message: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated  and Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Comment: @pollux1er Thanks for feedback. I will investigate further and let you know if i will get solution.

Comment: @pollux1er please have a look on [this](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute)

Comment: thanks  for this useful link. I tested @Nadeshwaran and it is working. IT uses directly R&OS pdf class to donwload the file and it works fine ! Thanks for the help