# how to include pdf download in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to keep a button to download the pdf file. But Library files gets displayed in the view. someone please help me.thanks in advance.
  Controller code:

```
public function pdf()
{
    //load library
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
   // retrieve data from model
    $data['DocFile'] = $this->Docauth->get_items();
    $data['DocFileName'] = "items";
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); 
   // boost the memory limit if it's low ;)
    $html = $this->load->view('Docauth_v', $data, true);
   // render the view into HTML
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
    $output = 'Docauth' . date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '_.pdf';
    $pdf->Output("$output", 'I'); // save to file because we can
    exit();
```

view file

```
<div class="form-group">                                                            
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">View File</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input name="DocFile" id="DocFile" class="form-control"` type="text" >
    </div>
    <a href="Docauth/pdf"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615451/download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-displaying-it-with-codeigniter

Comment: Have you tried sending header information before output (content-type, content-disposition) ?

Comment: More to the point have you tried a google search `"pdf download codeigniter"`. It does generate about a 1,000,000 things for you to look at

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a PDF file instead of displaying it with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615451/download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-displaying-it-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

The `I` option in the `Output` function sends the file inline to the browser. You need to use the `D` option :

```
$pdf->Output("$output", 'D');
```

More info here : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.1/TCPDF%3AOutput

> **@ param string :dest**
>
> Destination where to send the document. It can take one of the
>   following values:
>
> I: send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used
>   if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the
>   “Save as” option on the link generating the PDF.
>
> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given
>   by name.
>
> F: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
>
> S: return the document as a string. name is ignored.
>
> FI: equivalent to F + I option
>
> FD: equivalent to F + D option